# Ошибка: cannot convert 'stack()' to 'stack' in assignment

Tags: c++

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
bool flag=0;
int i;

struct stack
{
char data;
stack *prev;
};

stack *input()
{
stack *ptr, *tmptr;
cout << "Vvedite simvoly, posled element = 0" << endl;
for (i=0; ; i++)
{
    ptr = new stack;
    if (i!=0)
    {
        ptr -> prev = tmptr;
    }
    cin >> ptr -> data;
    if (ptr -> data == '-')
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if(ptr -> data == '0')
    {return ptr;}
    tmptr=ptr;
}
return ptr;
}

 void output (stack *ptr)
{
int n=i;
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    cout << ptr->data << endl;
    ptr=ptr->prev;
}
}

int main()
{
stack *ptr;
ptr=input;
output(ptr);
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Вывод компилятора

> 9 cannot convert 'stack*()' to 'stack*' in assignment

Comment: @stupidmonkey, укажите строку хотя бы

Comment: в строке 50

Comment: Хорошо, что-то сегодня голова не думает, знал что пустяк какой-то но найти не мог

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ptr=input;// - 50-я строка, неправильно
```

вот так правильно:

```
ptr = input();// это ж функция
```